# How can I correctly parse this specific Date?

Tags: java, date, date-format, simpledateformat

I could not find a correctly and clean working solution for my Date which is formatted like this:

> 2014-06-09T00:01+0200

(9th of June here)

Last I tried was this:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

This just gives me an unparsable date exception. What do you think I should change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace `XXX` with `Z`,

```
String dateTimestr = "2014-06-09T00:01+0200";
SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ");
s.parse(dateTimestr);
```

***to print,***

```
System.out.println(s.format(s.parse(dateTimestr)));
```

**using Java 8,**

```
OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("2014-06-09T00:01+02:00");
System.out.println(dateTime.toString());
```

Note that `OffsetDateTime.parse` would only work if your string is proper [ISO8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) date format. If your date is in different format then you have to provide your `OffsetDateTime.parse()` with a proper formatter using `DateTimeFormatter`. i.e

```
OffsetDateTime.parse(yourStringDate, DateTimeFormatter formatter)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Z` instead of `XXX` or one `X`

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> Z  Time zone  RFC 822 time zone -0800
>
> X  Time zone  ISO 8601 time zone -08; -0800; -08:00

Answer (score 0):

The problem is XXX requires timezone format with a colon, i.e., 2014-06-09T00:01+02:00

Using Z instead of XXX or using XX (2 X's) should accept format without colon

Be careful with using one X as some have posted because this will disregard the last two digits of the timezone (e.g., 2014-06-09T00:01+02). This could be problematic if working with time zones in some countries like India where the time zone offset is +05:30. Note the following code..

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmXXX").format(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmX").parse("2014-06-09T00:01+05:30")));
```

Will print 2014-06-08T14:01-05:00. The :30 in the timezone was lost when using one X. [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#iso8601timezone)